# Is there a way to refresh an extract upon some data change?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement, due to which I need to refresh an extract as soon as new data arrive in the database.

I have tried with custom code using tabcmd

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to setup an incremental extract refresh that you schedule on Tableau Server to run every 15 minutes. The extract will pick up new data when available.

[Incremental Extracts](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_refresh.htm)

If you are not on Tableau Server you will have to do something with Python and Tableau's [Extract API](https://www.tableau.com/data-extract-api) to check your tables for new records and then rebuild your extracts accordingly.

Comment: The minimum time possible on Tableau Server to automate refreshes is __15 minutes__

Answer (score 0):

The [REST API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#run_extract_refresh_task) can refresh extracts.

Here is an interesting article on the [Tableau Community Forum](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236223) which seems similar to your situation with regards to difficulty using TabCMD and an introduction to the logic behind using the REST API. There is a good discussion and many examples of blogs which outline the coding process.

Comment: If this ends up working for you, please upvote and apply green check/tick mark for so that others may reference the correct answer. Thank you!